# Determine if element is child of another in React, with consideration for portals

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-portal

I currently determine if the user has clicked on a child element by using a ref to capture the root element of my component and checking if the click target is `root.contains(target)`.

However, some child components use React portals to render their content outside of the component's root element in the DOM, even though they're still descendants in the React hierarchy. I know that this component hierarchy must be preserved somewhere. Is it possible for me to get access to it, and to determine simply if an element is a "React child" of another?

Comment: Even though a portal can be anywhere in the DOM tree, it behaves like a normal React child in every other way because of even bubbling. whether you want to consider them as child or not?if yes then you can achieve with the way you are doing

Comment: @d-saurabh You can't do it my way because the `contains` method is directly on the DOM element, not intercepted and reinterpreted by React.

Answer (score 0):

The event bubbles through two areas (the Portal section and the monitoring section), which can be flagged by intercepting the event.

See: [ClickAwayListener Code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/packages/material-ui/src/ClickAwayListener/ClickAwayListener.js)